# javasript - sort a list with words

Tags: javascript

I have a list with book names and I would like to sort every other word on the list in two different tables, is it possible?

```
var List = require("collections/list");

var livre = new List(['HarryPotter', 'Dracula', 'SeigneurDesAnneaux', 'Simetierre', 'Malefique', 'Desolation']);

livre.toArray();

livre.sort();

console.log(livre.join(' - '));
```

thank's

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Just iterate through the list by odd or even indeces, then you have the "every other" rule in place.

Comment: `List` object, what framework are you using?

Comment: @gorak I would like HarryPotter, SeigneurDesAnneaux and Malefique stay in the list and the others are in another after the sorting.

Comment: @JózefPodlecki I'm sorry, I don't understand: /

Comment: @Terry But how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), then [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as follows:

```js
const words = ['HarryPotter', 'Dracula', 'SeigneurDesAnneaux', 'Simetierre', 'Malefique', 'Desolation'];
const array1 = words.filter((w, i) => i % 2 == 0).sort(); 
const array2 = words.filter((w, i) => i % 2 != 0).sort(); 

console.log(array1.join(' - '));
console.log(array2.join(' - '));
```

Comment: Thank's! but it's possible that Malefique is in the first array ? There, in the output it is in the second array

Comment: In that case you would first have to create the arrays using `Array.filter()`, then sort the resulting arrays.